# Laravel 5.5 : 419 unknown status with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, forms, laravel, csrf

I am requesting `POST` :

Route :

`Route::post('/register','CommonController@postRegister')->name('register');`

CSRF Meta tag :

`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

```
$("#submitSalonForm").click(function(e) {
  $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
  });
  $.ajax({
      url: "/register",
      type: "post",
      data: new FormData($('form')[1]),
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success:function(response) {
          return alert('Form 2 submitted');
      }
  });
});
```

**And the exception :**

[image: Exception screenshot]

**The exception comes sometimes and sometimes the code runs smoothly, I have no idea what am i missing here.**

Comment: What does the trace say?  Seems like there could be something useful there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change ajax method from post to get

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Ajx call:

```
let formData = $('form').serializeArray();
$.ajax({
      url: "/register",
      type: "POST",
      data: {formData, "_token": $('#token').val()},
      cache: false,
      datatype: 'JSON',
      processData: false,
      success: function (response) {
           console.log(response);
         },
         error: function (response) {
           console.log(response);
         }
  });
```

Your route is get

```
Route::get('/register','CommonController@showRegister')->name('register');
```

Ajax call is making a post request, laravel sqwaks with a http exception.

**EDIT:**
Laravel 419 post error is usually related with api.php and token authorization

So try to include the token on ajax body instead like above.

Comment: My bad, The route is post, I have updated the question.

Comment: @Gammer where is new Form Data function ?

Comment: There is no function for that, Its just `new FormData($('form')[1])` ! Really !

Comment: Still the same issue, Some times it works sometimes its not, When i spent some time filling the form it gives me 419, But when i do it fast it runs ok.

Comment: 419 means token missmatch exception, so include the token on ajax body instead,

Comment: But we are attaching the token, Right ?

Comment: only when you press "#submitSalonForm' token will be included.

Answer (score 2):

---

In addition to putting the crsf-token value in the header meta tag you need to pass it through in your AJAX requests like:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   headers: {
     'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to setup ajax separately. Laravel automatically generates a CSRF "token" for each active user session managed by the application. Get the token with this:

```
var token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
```

Pass the token in `data`

```
var token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
var formData = new FormData($('form')[1])
$.ajax({
    url : '/register',
    data : {_token:token,formData:formData},
    type: 'post',
    ...
})
```

Comment: No effect, Same 419 exception :(, Its killing me

Comment: If it bothers you that much I have a very bad idea. Exclude this route from csrf verification from `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know I am too late, but I did face the exact issue you face.

I was 100% sure that the token has been sent with the request, but the issue is still.

So, after too many searches I finally got it fixed by following these steps:

```
php artisan config:clear          
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
```